# custom typings files to angular 6

Tags: angular6, typescript2.0

I am trying to ad some custom typings definition file in angular  but facing some error.

in app folder I have external folder in which I have external.d.ts file and below code

```
declare function format(input: string, ...args): string;
```

in tsconfig.json I tried adding 
"files": ["/app/external/external.d.ts"]

but its not working.

can somebody give me idea about adding custom typings file to angular 6.

Answer (score 20):

Add the custom typing file to `typeRoots` in tsconfig.json in the root folder work for me.

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/typings.d.ts"],
```

Comment: Thanks @Unheilg, 
You made my day as i was struggling with the issue since long time and unable to figure out this small mistake of my project configuration.

Comment: I don't see `typeRoots` in my `tsconfig.json` file. Is this a root node in that json file?

Answer (score 6):

The correct property is **types** inside tsconfig.json:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, can you elaborate on why it didn't work for you?

Comment: Because as the doc explains, "typeRoots" refers to a list of directories, but "types" refers to specific files. Since we want to inform our file named 'typings.d.ts' makes sense to use the key "types"  instead of "typeRoots".