# Calling custom jQuery function inside Angular Component class

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, function

I have one custom query function written in a javascript file under the source folder (i.e. /src/assets/inlineedit.js) of Angular application.

Here's the content of the file.

```
$.fn.inlineEdit = function(replaceWith, connectWith) {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    $(this).click(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.hide();
        elem.after(replaceWith);
        replaceWith.focus();
        replaceWith.blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                connectWith.val($(this).val()).change();
                elem.text($(this).val());
            }
            $(this).remove();
            elem.show();
        });
    });
};
```

Now, I want to call this function within Angular mycomponent.ts file and content looks as below:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef  } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pivotgrid',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.css']
})
export class mycomponent {
    OnCellclick (event): void
    {
       var replaceWith = $('<input name="temp" type="text" />'),
            connectWith = $('input[name="hiddenField"]');

        $('#innerDiv').inlineEdit(replaceWith, connectWith);
    } 
}
```

But, I'm getting error like

> Property 'inlineEdit' does not exist on type 'JQuery'

How to call jQuery functions inside Angular components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `<any>` type-casting like this:

```
(<any>$('#innerDiv')).inlineEdit(replaceWith, connectWith);
```

---

Or even better:

First install `@types/jquery` from `npm`

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

Then add a local typings file and declare your plugin function in it

```
interface JQuery {
  <your-plugin-name>(options?: any): any;
}
```

Then you can use your plugin.

Source: https://medium.com/all-is-web/angular-5-using-jquery-plugins-5edf4e642969

Comment: It is showing `ERROR TypeError: $(...).inlineEdit is not a function`

Comment: Did you import your `inlineedit.js` file in the `scripts` section of the `angular.json` file? And did you install `jquery` and imported it too?

Comment: Yeah, I did all of that. But still facing the same issue. Where do I create `typings.d.ts` file?

Comment: You create a file (you can give any name) in a desired path and import it in `tsconfig.json` file in `src` location. Check this thread out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876748/custom-typings-files-to-angular-6

Comment: Everything is working fine now, except the function signature. `interface JQuery {
    inlineEdit(options?: any): any;
}`. Here, it is allowed only one parameter. How I can write it for my jQuery function which takes 2 parameters?

Comment: You can add much parameter as you want in the declaration. `interface JQuery { inlineEdit(replaceWith: any, connectWith: any): any; }`